# Noob question updating variable in a function

Tags: python

I was watching a online guide about calling a function to calculate a square root using the Newton method:

[image: screenshot showing Newton method formula]

What I cannot get my head around is that you need to update the variable in the `for` loop to get the result.

Can anyone help me figuring out the logic behind this?

```
def compute_sqrt(n, num_loops):
    result = n/2
    
    for i in range(num_loops):
        result_1 = (result + n/result) / 2
        result = result_1
        
    return result_1

computesqrt(n=100,num_loops=10)
```

Comment: This sounds like you don't fully understand the logarithm, since you ask about the need to update a variable in a loop. The formula you link to actually has an arrow pointing to a previous step, indicating a loop (step 2 -> step 3 -> step 2 -> step 3 etc), so it's unclear where you don't understand how the code matches the formula.

Comment: So, what do you think that the Newton Method is doing? btw the `for` loop only needs: `result = (result + n/result) / 2`

Comment: Well, this is not really programming question. It is the method/formula. Even in the image you link there is the loop-back arrow on the left-hand-side. If you have problem with understanding Newton method you may ask on [math stackexchage](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the community!! I propose you to do it by hand in a piece of paper and you will see the program behaviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using result with every iteration in the for loop, you would want to update result to be result_1, or else you will keep using the initial result value in each iteration